# Node.js slice single file into multiple images

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, slice

I am trying to slice a file that contains multiple images on a Node.js server. I tried to use data.slice(start, end) but it won't let me start anywhere but 0. If I start at a positive or negative number, the image doesn't load and instead there is a weird windows download of unknown file type. I am now trying image-to-slices but that is giving me errors when I try to download node-canvas. I am on a company computer that has a proxy, but I set up the proxy correctly when installing Node so I don't know why it would block this. Any help on how to split a file or why this won't download is greatly appreciated!

I attached my error message (linked because I'm a new user so it won't let me post images) trying to install node-canvas at node-gyp rebuild. I had to black out my user id based on corporate rules but the file paths should still make sense.
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TfuSH.png)

Comment: Are the images in your file separated by any headers? Maybe you can utilize them and extract. Can you also post a sample of what the file looks like (JSON etc) ?

Comment: I can't post sample files but it's thousands of lines of hex code like "ffd8 ffe0 0010 4a46 4946 0001 0100 0001 0001 0000 ffdb 0084 0009 0607 1010 0f15 100f 1215 1515 1516 1516 1515 1515 1715 1516 1719 1a1d 1716 1515 151b 2028 2018". Eventually I would like to be able to extract by headers but currently I'm am just separating by bytes. Any advice on either way of doing these are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you convert the hex to base64 format and see if it works?

Comment: Didn't work with slice and image-to-slices wont work since canvas can't download